# How to deploy a parachute?

Tags: assassins-creed-brotherhood

I have finished Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood (on the PS3) and all of the Leonardo's War Machines. He gave me parachutes. I bought a large bag but I can't figure out which button to press in order to deploy a parachute.

Answer (score 1):

[**On the PS3**](http://static2.cdn.ubi.com/manuals/assassinscreed/brotherhood/controller/ps3/ACROM4810_PS3_ControllerMap.pdf), the key to deploy the parachute - and subsequently cut it - is the *Square button: <kbd>□</kbd>*.

[**On the Xbox 360**](http://static2.cdn.ubi.com/manuals/assassinscreed/brotherhood/controller/x360/ACROM4710_X360_ControllerMap.pdf), the button to open the parachute is <kbd>X</kbd>, while <kbd>B</kbd> cuts it.

You need to be jumping off an edge to successfully open the parachute.